# Question re. IIS worker process timeout and ASP.NET session timeout

Tags: asp.net, iis

The idle timeout in IIS appears to revert back to its original value every new request, so if I started out with 20mins then I get a fresh 20mins again. Is this correct?

What about for the session timeout?

Ronald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's same for Session timeout, it refreshes with every request, i-e the timeout is the time elapsed between two consecutive request from the same user/browser.